# Plotting a graph with specific x-axis values

Tags: matplotlib

I have plotted a graph using data I have on excel and have the values of the x and y axes. However, I want to change the value on the x-axis by just presenting specific values which would reflect the key days on the axis only. Is that possible?

Here is the code I have written:

```
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt #download matplot library
#create a graph of the cryptocurrencies in excel

btc = pd.read_excel('/Users/User/Desktop/bitcoin_prices.xlsx') 
btc.set_index('Date', inplace=True) #Chart Fit
btc.plot()
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize= 12)
plt.ylabel('Price ($)', fontsize= 12)
plt.title('Cryptocurrency Prices', fontsize=15)
plt.figure(figsize=(60,40))
plt.show() #plot then show the file
```

Thank you.

Comment: please provide some sample data and an expected output. Otherwise it is quite much impossible to guess what exactly you want.

Comment: Please supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the program to recognize the `datetime` format of the `'Date'` column. Supply `parse_dates=['Dates']` to the loading call. Then you can index your data for certain days. For example:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

btc = pd.read_csv('my_excel_data.xlsx', parse_dates=['Dates'], index_col='Dates')

selected_time = np.arange(dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2016, 1, 1), dt.timedelta(7))
btc_2015 = btc.loc[selected_time, :]
```

If you want specific labels for specific dates you have to read into [axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html) and [date formatters](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html)